# Issues running first ruby on rails, "sqlite -v 1.3.10"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

Everytime I run `bundle install`, I get this output:

```
Shaheens-MacBook-Air:blog ShaheenG$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.0
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.4.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.4 
Using tzinfo 1.2.2 
Using activesupport 4.1.8
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.8
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.1.8
Using mime-types 2.4.3
Using mail 2.6.3 
Using actionmailer 4.1.8 
Using activemodel 4.1.8 
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214 
Using activerecord 4.1.8 
Using bundler 1.6.2 
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0 
Using execjs 2.2.2 
Using coffee-script 2.3.0 
Using thor 0.19.1 
Using railties 4.1.8
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using jbuilder 2.2.5
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.3
Using sprockets-rails 2.2.1
Using rails 4.1.8
Using rdoc 4.1.2
Using sass 3.2.19
Using sass-rails 4.0.4
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using spring 1.2.0

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
  checking for sqlite3.h...

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries
and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
  --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib  --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog   --srcdir=.  --curdir
  --ruby=/Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
  --with-sqlite3-dir  --without-sqlite3-dir   --with-sqlite3-include
  --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include  --with-sqlite3-lib
  --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

/Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
(RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.
   from /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
   from /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1120:in `block in find_header'
   from /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:918:in `block in checking_for'
   from /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
   from /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
   from /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
   from /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
   from /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
   from /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:917:in `checking_for'
   from /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:1119:in `find_header'
   from extconf.rb:30:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection. Results logged to
/Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.10/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler
cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'`
succeeds before bundling. Shaheens-MacBook-Air:blog ShaheenG$
```

How do I get this to correctly install? I've tried searching and using `brew install sqlite3`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Verbatim from your stack trace: `You have to install development tools first`

You'll need to download and install XCode Command Line Tools to compile native extensions.

Comment: Hey Musannif! Just wokeup and checked this thread to find answers. Currently downloading command line tools for mac osx yosemite, ill let you know if it works!

Comment: nope same error, after installing;
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/ShaheenG/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Comment: Did you open a new shell after installation? What does mkmf.log state?